# Gerrit hook API

Tags: gerrit

I'm using Gerrit Code review.

I have a problem with it. There are some hooks with Gerrit, one of them is:

```
patchset-created --change <change id> --change-url <change url>
--project <project name> --branch <branch> --uploader <uploader>
--commit <sha1> --patchset <patchset id>
```

Gerrit will call it if you push some change to Gerrit.

The commit parameter passed in is the sha1 commit number, but what I want is the commit log. For example, if I do `git commit -m "id:110"`, I want to get `id:110`.

How can I get it? Is there any API I can use?

Comment: Good idea. But why not try subscribe the project and get notifications.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i have solve the problem myself.it seems that gerrit has not such apis.
but , if patchset-created hook is called , the change parameter it passed in is usefull,
if refer to a private key of gerrit database table ,named Change ,every git push to gerrit it record such change to the Change table , include the commit message , so , you can use the change parameter to query the table , so got the commit message from the hook  !

Answer (score 5):

You can use git log or git show, run from within the correct repository.  Your hook will be passed the repo via --repository.  The hook will be called from a useful working directory (I just checked into this last week, I think it cd's into the repo before running the hook?)

`git log $SHA1` or `git show $SHA1` depending on which information you want.

That said, I'd prefer a better solution.  I'm looking to add the diff / patchset to the information, and it is not available via any of the gerrit hooks.

Comment: I think he want to get commit message, not SHA of the commit

Comment: The hook is given the SHA. It can look up the diff or log message by running git commands inside of the hook code.  It would be much cleaner if gerrit had the info available via api, but this hacky approach does work. (At least it did in 2011 when I answerred)